# Magento 2 payment method code on order success page

Tags: magento2, orders, payment-methods

I trying to get the payment method name on order success page on magento 2 but unable to get the data.

i did so far

> checkout_onepage_success.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="order.success.additional.info">
        <block class="Vendor\Ordersuccess\Block\Checkout\Success"
               name="vendor.order.success"
               template="Vendor_Ordersuccess::order/success.phtml"
               after="-">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

> Block page

```
namespace Vendor\Ordersuccess\Block\Checkout;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Success {


    public function getPaymentMethod() {
         $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($this->getLastOrderId());
         var_dump(json_decode($order->toArray()));exit;
    }

}
```

> susess.phtml

```
<?php echo __('Custom template file content.'); ?>
<?php 

var_dump($block->getPaymentMethod());exit;
//echo $block->getSomething(); ?>
```

I want to get payment detiails on order success please.

Comment: How about your issue?

Answer (score 1):

We can get by using checkout session. Your `Vendor\Ordersuccess\Block\Checkout\Success` should be:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Ordersuccess\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Success {

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * Success constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param OrderFactory $orderFactory
     * @param Session $session
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        Session $session,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $session;
        parent::__construct($context, $orderFactory, $data);
    }

    public function getPaymentMethod() {

        $payment = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getPayment();
    }

}
```

Comment: return NULL even `$this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()` return Null version 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

you should implement the __construct ()

`

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
 */
protected $_checkoutSession;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
 */
protected $_customerSession;


/** 
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
 * @param \Magento\Paypal\Model\Billing\AgreementFactory $agreementFactory
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


public function getPaymentMethod(){
    return $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getPayment()->toArray();
}
```

`